# Are torsors over unipotent groups trivial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homogeneous-spaces, arithmetic-geometry

I might have misunderstood something I heard somewhere.

Are torsors over unipotent groups trivial?

I couldn't find this in some standard references.

Comment: Dear Harry, I don't mean to be rude, but you have really been asking a flurry of questions these last few days! I would suggest both that you mull questions over in your mind and search the literature a bit more before asking here (it builds character), and that you make sure to take the time to digest the answers you have received. 

Comment: Alright. I will.

Comment: Over nonperfect fields there are nontrivial torsors for unipotent groups, e.g., Exercise (3), top of p. 130, Serre's "Galois Cohomology"

Comment: Just adding to Jason's comment that over perfect fields the torsors are indeed trivial.

Comment: Also an expert reminded me that, if one allows non-smooth "unipotent" groups and torsors in the fppf topology rather than the etale topology, then there are many other examples.